# limit the width of view for header and view for footer of a UItableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

In the screenshot below, the blue colored line is the header and footer of the sections of my `tableView` (In the `tableView`, I am treating rows as sections).

However, i want the blue line to be just below the row of the `tableView` (of same width as the row). Any idea how to do it??

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *headerView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 333, 1)] ;
    headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return headerView;
}

-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *footerView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 333, 1)] ;
    footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return footerView;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add UIView with Blue color above the UIView for which set the background color to Clear Color

```
-(UIView*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

UIView *dummyfooterView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 2)] ;
dummyfooterView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

// Widht should be less than dummyfooterView
UIView *footerView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 320-20, 2)] ;
footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
[dummyfooterView addSubview:footerView];
return dummyfooterView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 2;
}
```

I am not sure though, hope this may help you! The output will be like below screen. I have used Grouped tableview style here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to add 1px view at bottom of cell at row at indexpath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MessageBoxCell";
    LGMessageBoxCell *cell = (LGMessageBoxCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    UIView *headerView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.fram.size.height - 1, cell.fram.size.width, 1)] ;
   headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    cell.backgroundView = headerView;
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Set height for header and fooder

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 58;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   return 58;
}
```

Comment: But your header view and fooder view height will 58, it not fit with height 1.